# Can't connect postgres on docker to spring project

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, jdbc

i have a docker file on spring boot like this

```
 services:
    postgres:
      container_name: newlife
      image: postgres
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: local
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: local
        PGDATA: /data/postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres:/data/postgres
      ports:
        - "8081:8081"
      networks:
        - postgres
      restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      postgres:
        driver: bridge
   volumes:
     postgres:
```

and this is the application

```
server:
  port: 1101

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8081/online
    username: local
    password: local

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
  main:
    web-application-type: servlet
```

the error says connection attempt failed and when i check the docker logs when the spring try to connect it will suddenly shut down like in this logs

```
2023-09-15 13:04:18 2023-09-15 06:04:18.507 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.4 (Debian 15.4-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2023-09-15 13:04:18 2023-09-15 06:04:18.508 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-09-15 13:04:18 2023-09-15 06:04:18.508 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-09-15 13:04:18 2023-09-15 06:04:18.512 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-09-15 13:04:18 2023-09-15 06:04:18.517 UTC [66] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-09-15 06:04:18 UTC
2023-09-15 13:04:18 2023-09-15 06:04:18.521 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-09-15 13:09:18 2023-09-15 06:09:18.625 UTC [64] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2023-09-15 13:09:22 2023-09-15 06:09:22.791 UTC [64] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 44 buffers (0.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=4.148 s, sync=0.007 s, total=4.169 s; sync files=12, longest=0.004 s, average=0.001 s; distance=252 kB, estimate=252 kB
2023-09-15 13:04:18 server stopped
2023-09-15 13:04:18 
2023-09-15 13:04:18 PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
2023-09-15 13:04:18
```

i think i have config it right or do i miss something?

Comment: Is your Spring Boot application also running on Docker? If so, you need to use `newlife` instead of `localhost`. Also, your port mapping is wrong, PostgreSQL listens on 5432, yet you're mapping  port 8081.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem you are encountering is because of how you have setup your network. You reference the network as `localhost`, but you're running in a custom network bridge you have called "postgres". `localhost` in your Spring application refers to the host local to the Spring application, and if that is not running in Docker in the same network, it won't reach. You can run Spring in another Docker container, define them in the same compose file and use the "magic" DNS property of Docker and just reference it using the service name:

```
url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/online
```

It could also be the fact that PostgreSQL runs on port 5432 by default, and you have opened 8081 and mapped it to 8081 instead of 5432 which is the default. If you could clarify how you're running your Spring application it would make for a better answer.

Comment: right now i have make the postgres manually and run them on 172.17.0.2:5432, and install pgadmin on another container name x and try to access it from the x container with 172.17.0.2:5432 and its works but when i put it on my spring application nothing works the error say the connection attemp failed

Comment: or do i access it wrongf